# Selenium ChromeDriver 101.0.4951.41 cannot start DevTools

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools

[image]

Hi. I tried upgrade my chromedriver to 101.0.4951.41 today and it sudden keep prompt this error to me. Anything I missed or what I should add for new version?

And this is my code:

```
    options.AddArgument("start-maximized");
    options.AddArgument("--disable-extensions");
    options.AddArgument("--disable-blink-features");
    options.AddArgument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled");
    options.AddArgument("--disable-gpu");
    options.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
    options.AddArgument("--allow-running-insecure-content");
    options.AddArgument("--ignore-certificate-errors");
    options.AddArgument("--disable-background-networking");

    options.AddExcludedArguments(new List<string>() { "enable-automation" });
    options.AddUserProfilePreference("credentials_enable_service", false);
    options.AddUserProfilePreference("password_manager_enabled", false);

    ChromeDriverService chromeDriverService=ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
    chromeDriverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

    IWebDriver Driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, options);

    IDevTools devTools = Driver as IDevTools;
    IDevToolsSession session = devTools.GetDevToolsSession();
```

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). You may like to consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Which version of Chrome are you running? If it worked one day, but not the next, maybe Chrome auto-updated when you weren't expecting it to? (or *didn't* auto-update when you expected?)

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by adding the protocol version (i.e.)

using DevTools = OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V96;
:
:
IDevTools devTools = webDriver as IDevTools;
IDevToolsSession session = devTools.GetDevToolsSession(96);

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue and it seems in versions above and equal 100 need to have the remote-debugging-port argument set.

Add this to args:

```
"--remote-debugging-port=9222"
```

Answer (score 0):

This opens the devtools for me when I open the driver itself. I tested it on version 101.0.4951.41 so it should work fine for you. (no remote debugging port required)

`options.AddArgument("--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs");`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the new version of chromedriver (101.0.4951.41) is not compatible with old version of DevTools

I can solved this issue updated Selenium.WebDriver to 4.1.1 and used "OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V101.Network"